# When should I wrap variables with ${...} in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I wonder why often variables in CMake are wrapped with a dollar sign and curly brackets. For example, I saw this call [in a CMake tutorial](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake).

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

But from what I tried, this does the same thing.

```
include_directories(PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)
```

When is the wrapping with `${...}` needed and what does it mean? Why are variables often wrapped with this even if it makes no difference?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Quoting [the CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references):

> A *variable reference* has the form `${variable_name}` and is evaluated
> inside a Quoted Argument or an Unquoted Argument. A variable reference
> is replaced by the value of the variable, or by the empty string if
> the variable is not set.

In other words, writing `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR` refers, literally, to the string "PROJECT_BINARY_DIR". Encapsulating it in `${...}` gives you *the contents* of the variable with the name PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.

Consider:

```
set(FOO "Hello there!")
message(FOO)     # prints FOO
message(${FOO})  # prints Hello there!
```

As you have probably guessed already, `include_directories(PROJECT_BINARY_DIR)` simply attempts to add a subdirectory of the name PROJECT_BINARY_DIR to the include directories. On most build systems, if no such directory exists, it will simply ignore the command, which might have tricked you into the impression that it works as expected.

A popular source of confusion comes from the fact that `if()` does not require explicit dereferencing of variables:

```
set(FOO TRUE)
if(FOO)
    message("Foo was set!")
endif()
```

Again [the documentation explains this behavior](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html):

> `if(<constant>)`
>
> True if the constant is 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number. False if the constant is 0, OFF, NO, FALSE, N, IGNORE, NOTFOUND, the
> empty string, or ends in the suffix -NOTFOUND. Named boolean constants
> are case-insensitive. If the argument is not one of these constants,
> it is treated as a variable.
>
> `if(<variable>)`
>
> True if the variable is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise. (Note macro arguments are not variables.)

In particular, one can come up with weird examples like:

```
unset(BLA)
set(FOO "BLA")
if(FOO)
    message("if(<variable>): True")
else()
    message("if(<variable>): False")
endif()
if(${FOO})
    message("if(<constant>): True")
else()
    message("if(<constant>): False")
endif()
```

Which will take the `TRUE` branch in the variable case, and the `FALSE` branch in the constant case. This is due to the fact that in the constant case, CMake will go look for a variable `BLA` to perform the check on (which is not defined, hence we end up in the FALSE branch).

Comment: How does something like `if (SFML_FOUND)` work then?

Comment: `if()` is a special case, as it works on both variables and values. While `if(SFML_FOUND)` and `if(${SFML_FOUND})` might both work, they actually do different things: Check [the documentation for `if`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html) and pay special attention to the difference between `if(<constant>)` and `if(<variable>)`. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The documentation does not explain how `<condition>` and `<condN>` work: is each expression allowed to be `<variable>|<constant>` or does it only apply to the top-level forms? *Usages* appear to indicate it applies to all forms.

Answer (score 1):

it's per-case. it's poorly defined. You just have to look it up.
there are other places where you don't have to use {}'s to use the contents of the variable, besides IF. Yikes.