# How to test if CMake found a library with find_library

Tags: cmake

I find the library with the `find_library` function

```
find_library(MY_LIB lib PATHS ${MY_PATH})
```

If the library is found, `${MY_LIB}` will point to the correct location.
If the library is not found `${MY_LIB}` will be `MY_LIB-NOTFOUND`.

But how do I test this?

```
if(${MY_LIB} EQUAL 'MY_LIB-NOTFOUND') 
    ...
endif()
```

always evaluates to false.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can simply test the variable as such, e.g.:

```
find_library(LUA_LIB lua)
if(NOT LUA_LIB)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "lua library not found")
endif()
```

Example output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:99 (message):
  lua library not found


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Note that we use

```
if(NOT LUA_LIB)
```

and not

```
if(NOT ${LUA_LIB})
```

because of the [different semantics](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html).

With `${}`, the variable `LUA_LIB` is substitued before `if()` is evaluated. As
part of the evaluation the content would then be interpreted as variable name,
unless it matches the definition of a constant. And this isn't what we want.

Answer (score 11):

Simply do

```
if(MY_LIB)
    #found
    ...
else()
    #not found
    ...
endif()
```

Comment: @sighol: Yeah, it doesn't matter that much here afaik

Comment: @sighol In particular note in the [documentation of the if command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/if.html): *False if the constant is 0, OFF, NO, FALSE, N, IGNORE, NOTFOUND, the empty string, or* **ends in the suffix -NOTFOUND**.

Comment: @NaCl The `${}` in the `if` really should go away. I explained the implications of leaving them in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25809646/577603). The issue is very subtle and in 99% of the cases, it doesn't make a difference, but when it does, you usually spend half a day debugging it.

Comment: @Antonio wow, just knew '-NOTFOUND' suffix also means 'false' in CMake.